# how can I call this.setState() properly in this context?

Tags: react-native

How can I call this.setState() properly in this context?

I have the following function in my ForgotPassword screen

```
handleForgotPassword(){

  if(!this.validateInputs()) return;

  const {email} = this.state;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  //const setState = this.setState;

  auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(function() {
    this.setState({passwordEmailSent:true});
  }).catch(function(error) {
    //alert(error.message);
    let errorMessage;
    if(error.message.includes('There is no user')){
      errorMessage = 'No users match the provided email address';
      this.setState({errorMessage});    
    }
  });
}
```

this.setState in the catch is returning the following error:

TypeError: this.setState is not a function

What can I do to structure this properly in order to call setState() when an error occurs?

=====UPDATE=====

Ok I'm still having issues with this implementation so I created an alternative class with a stripped down implementation to post for review.  The current error being returned when I try to use this.setState() in the provided code is:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.setState)

There are different ways to manage "this" usage scenarios in React.  Based on some googling, it looks like binding the fuctions to "this" in the constructor is recommended by the React team.  I like this approach as well b/c it provides a clear and consistent approach.  So can you provide some clarity as to why this code currently sees this.setState() as undefined and what modifications I can make to the code to fix this?

Code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export default class ForgotPassword2 extends React.Component {
  state = { email: '', errorMessage: null, passwordEmailSent:false }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.validateInputs = this.validateInputs.bind(this);
    this.handleForgotPassword = this.handleForgotPassword.bind(this);
  }

  validateInputs(){
    const {email} = this.state;

    if(email.length === 0){
      this.setState({errorMessage:'Email is required'});
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

handleForgotPassword(){

  alert('function called');
  if(!this.validateInputs()) return;

  const {email} = this.state;
  const auth = firebase.auth();

  auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(function() {
    //this.setState({passwordEmailSent:true});
    alert('pwd reset email sent');
  }).catch(function(error) {
      alert(error.message);
    let errorMessage;
    if(error.message.includes('There is no user')){
      alert('no matching user');
      errorMessage = 'No users match the provided email address';
      this.setState({errorMessage});
    }
  });
}

render() {
    return(
      <View>
          {this.state.errorMessage &&
            <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>
              {this.state.errorMessage}
            </Text>}

          <TextInput
            onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
            value={this.state.email}
          />
          <Button onPress={this.handleForgotPassword} title="Send Email 2"></Button>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions and `this` will be the context of the component class:

```
handleForgotPassword = () => {

  if(!this.validateInputs()) return;

  const {email} = this.state;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  //const setState = this.setState;

  auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(() => {
    this.setState({passwordEmailSent:true});
  }).catch((error) => {
    //alert(error.message);
    let errorMessage;
    if(error.message.includes('There is no user')){
      errorMessage = 'No users match the provided email address';
      this.setState({errorMessage});    
    }
  });
}
```

Example without using arrow functions:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleForgotPassword = this.handleForgotPassword.bind(this);
}

handleForgotPassword(){
  const context = this;
  if(!context.validateInputs()) return;

  const {email} = context.state;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  //const setState = context.setState;

  auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(function() {
    context.setState({passwordEmailSent:true});
  }).catch(function(error) {
    //alert(error.message);
    let errorMessage;
    if(error.message.includes('There is no user')){
      errorMessage = 'No users match the provided email address';
      context.setState({errorMessage});    
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: ok that seems to be one option but what if I want to use a consistent function structure throughout my classes without the arrow function wrapper?  how could I handle that approach?

Comment: If you don't want to use arrow functions you would need to bind your method in the constructor and save the reference of `this` in a variable to use in any nested functions.

Comment: I tried structuring handleForgotPassword() as an arrow function

Then I updated the event handler call to this.handleForgotPassword

But I still get the following warning/failure in my emulator:

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')

Comment: Make sure the functions for `sendPasswordResetEmail` are also arrow functions.

Comment: I added some additional info under a new "======UPDATE=====" header in my original.  I created a stripped down version of the class but this.setState() is still not found from within the function

Comment: `auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(function() {` you need to use an arrow function here to have access to `this` inside `.then` or do what I did in the second code block where you save the context of `this` in a variable to use. Optionally you can also rewrite it to use `async/await`